# Yahoo Pipes and Regex with an html formatting issue

Tags: html, regex, yahoo-pipes

I am struggling to see how to use the regex to add a non-printable carriage return character into an html string.

Its a WordPress thing in that to auto-embed a video I need to put the URL on its own line in the html.

First I use a regex:

```
In item.vid_src replace ($) with \\r$1 
s is checked.
```

After which I am using a loop with a string builder in it - I am prefixing vid_src to the start of description thus:

```
item.vid_src
<br><br>
item.description

assign results to item.description
```

Before I include the Regex module in the pipe I get this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THA_5cqAfCQ<br><br><p><h1 class="MsoNormal">Cheetahs on
the edge</h1>
```

But I need this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THA_5cqAfCQ
<br><br><p><h1 class="MsoNormal">Cheetahs on the edge</h1>
```

Adding the regex module I get this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THA_5cqAfCQ&#92;r<br><br><p><h1 class="MsoNormal">
Cheetahs on the edge</h1>
```

Clearly its inserting exactly what I have asked for, but It is not what I was expecting, I need to get the html formatted with the newline. Does anybody have an insight as to how to tackle the problem?

Comment: Try `\r` instead of `\\r`.